# jekyll changing pre to p and adding th/td to tables

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to regenerate my site with jekyll but it's changing pre to p and adding th/td to tables.

Here's an example diff of the pre to p problem. The - indicates a line that was replaced with a + line. The code in markdown hasn't changed.

Diff

```
-<pre><code>-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy  -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
-</code></pre>
+<p><code>
+-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy  -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
+</code></p>
```

Markdown

````
```
RunScriptOnNode.Factory .runScript → create submit → submit
```
````

Here's an example diff of the th/td problem. The + indicates a new column that wasn't generated before and definitely isn't in my markdown file.

Diff

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
+     <th></th>
      <th> Column 1 </th>
      <th> Column 2 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
+     <td></td>
      <td> Value 1.1 </td>
      <td> Value 1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
+     <td></td>
      <td> Value 2.1 </td>
      <td> Value 2.2 </td>
    </tr>
...
```

Markdown

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 |
|------------|---------------------|
| Value 1.1 | Value 1.2
| Value 2.1 | Value 2.2
```

Why is jekyll doing this to my generated HTML files?

Comment: Did you change/update your markdown engine?

Comment: Very close. I was on rdiscount (2.0.7.3) and upgrading to rdiscount (2.1.6) solved the problem. Thanks! If you want to propose an answer of some sort, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these situations, it's wise to verify the versions of your markdown engine and/or if you can get the desired result by changing engines. :)